# PHP generate similar strings

Tags: php, string, random

How to generate similar output strings based on a single input string?
Tips: Output string:

1. can contain different length from input.
2. MUST contain only number, letter and hyphen (>126 <193 ; >64 <91 ; >=48 <=57 ; and 45 for hyphen)

I couldn't find a php function for this.

Comment: can you give some examples for input and output strings...

Comment: @Turcia
input: mydomain
output: mydomain-123; mydomain-mk;  mydomain-2

Comment: The reason you couldn't find a PHP function for this is because there isn't one -- it's too specialised. You need to write it yourself. What have you tried so far? We can help you fix problems you've found while writing it, but I doubt anyone will just step up and write it for you.

Comment: OK @SDC, thanks. I will try to write a function for this. And I will post it here for suggestions, fixes or for future references.

Comment: @XhevatZiberi as mentioned there's no function but you may find custom  slugify function from the web, which convert string to number, letter and hypen only form: http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to achieve a very simple solution which only takes into account some very basic limitation (this might be enough for your needs?):

```
$input = "mydomain";
$randomNum = rand(127,192);
$output = $input.'-'.$randomNum; // Now is mydomain-X where X is between 127 and 192
```